# Python - Boolean compare property for all elements in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

So I'm struggling to find a pythonic (or maybe I should say functional?) way to do this. I have a list of objects that I want to perform a Boolean compare on the object properties. I want the result to be true if every element evaluates to true and false if one element does not evaluate to true. Hopefully the code below shows what I am trying to do. I know that I can do this in a brute force way but I don't want to... lol

```
class obj
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

... somewhere else in the code

objects_list = list of class obj
bool_result  = true if all obj.x in list == some value
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help! The 'all' function was what I was missing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

```
print all(item.x == some_value for item in my_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Python for:

```
bool_result  = true if all obj.x in list == some value
```

is

```
bool_result = all(obj.x == some_value for obj in L)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bool_result = all(object.x == some_value for object in objects_list)`